# Facebook android native application not working on actual device

Tags: android, facebook, emulation

I developed an application which uses we can login to facebook and the logged user details can be stored. it is working fine when we run the application on emulator , but when we run the same application on android device it does not run .It only show the loading again and again but not showing the login window.

- I used the appID which facebook provided me.
- I used the hashkey as directed in facebook development section.

Overall application (i.e. facebook login window, returning the info of user ) is working well on different emulators but on actual device not even opening the login window it's just showing loading...

Comment: Stiffler can you try to ask an actual question here? I understand the problem, but what exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please Update below code of your application, it will solve your problem.

```
public void loginAndPostToWall() {
    facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
            new LoginDialogListener());
}
```