# Facebook integration app works perfect in Emulator but not on Android device

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app with Facebook integration. That works perfectly in emulator but does't work on android device.

That indicate some error...

App is  misconfiguration for Facebook login. press okay to go back to the application without connection Facebook.

But it solve with this using Hash key

Than after it not  store Access token and expires  in device so it not work proper in device.

It will work perfect in Emulator But not on device. Why?

I'm using Facebook Hackbook code to implement this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below link of my previous so answer, it will solve your problem.

[Facebook android native application not working on actual device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504823/facebook-android-native-application-not-working-on-actual-device/8877018#8877018)

Comment: @AmitPrajapati ok try it and if you have any query then tell me.

Comment: i  have on login click there is use this code for this ........  mFb.authorize(mActivity, mPermissions, mActivityCode, new LoginDialogListener());        where i want to do change on this

Comment: write mFb.authorize(mActivity, mPermissions, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
            new LoginDialogListener()); instead of your code line and tell me what happened.

Comment: can we do this without Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH but with Default Facebook app of my android device.

Answer (score 1):

You are using SSO so probably when you are testing on your device, you already have your Facebook installed and when you are testing on the emulator, you don't. One solution would be to use FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH - this way you separate you app from the official one. It is not recommended though.

I suggest you install the FB official application on the emulator too, and just let your app connect/disconnect through it. Don't save your SharedPreferences because your app will take them from the FB App.